# Can anyone tell what is being printed in this question?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int MAX = 4;

int main () {
const char *names[MAX] = { "Zara Ali", "Hina Ali", "Nuha Ali", "Sara Ali" };

   for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
      cout << "Value of names[" << i << "] = ";
      cout << (names + i) << endl;
   }

return 0;
}
```

what is (names + i) printing in the above code

what is char *names

Comment: Do you have any guesses as to what they are?

Comment: Have you tried going through the code step by step ?

Answer (score 1):

`names` is an array of `const char *` pointers, which are being initialized to point at string literals in memory (which is irrelevant to the code being shown).

When an array is referred to by its name alone, it *decays* into a pointer to the first element.  The loop is then using **pointer arithmetic** to increment that pointer to access each subsequent element.  Thus, the expression `names + i` is effectively the same as `&names[i]`, and so the loop is printing out the memory address of each element in the array, eg:

```
Value of names[0] = 0x7ffedc2f1850
Value of names[1] = 0x7ffedc2f1858
Value of names[2] = 0x7ffedc2f1860
Value of names[3] = 0x7ffedc2f1868
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/zogXYb)

Had the code used `*(names + i)` instead, then it would be dereferencing those addresses, thus printing out each `const char*` pointer in the array. `operator<<` is overloaded to handle `const char*` as a null-terminated string, thus the contents of the string literals would be printed instead of their addresses, eg:

```
Value of names[0] = Zara Ali
Value of names[1] = Hina Ali
Value of names[2] = Nuha Ali
Value of names[3] = Sara Ali
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/eelZDL)

Comment: This is incorrect.  What you describe would be true if `*(names + i)` was being printed.   The asterisk is missing.    `names + i` is a pointer to a pointer, not a pointer to the first character of a string.

Comment: @Peter you are right, I didn't see the missing dereference. I have fixed my answer.